# How do match the two strings which contains parentheses in perl

Tags: perl, matching

How do match the two strings which contains brackets.

the perl code is here.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$a = "cat(S1)rat";
$b = "cat(S1)r";

if ( $a =~ $b ) {
    printf("matching\n");
}
```

I am not getting the desired output.

please help

snk

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. `$a` and `$b` are different - why would you expect them to match in any way? Please describe what you are trying to accomplish, in more detail.

Comment: First put the input file and also expected output. Then just paste the code what you have done till now. Be specific then we can easily get your answer.

Comment: if $a="catrat" and $b="catr" I get the output "matching". But if I gave $a="cat(S1)rat" and $b="cat(S1)r" I do not get the output  "matching". Please help.

Comment: `(` and `)` are regex meta characters, so you need to escape them. Simplest way is to use the `\Q ... \E` escape, like you have done in your comment below.

Answer (score 3):

There are several answers here, but not a lot address your fundamental misunderstanding.

Here is a simplified version of your problem:

```
my $str = "tex(t)";
my $pattern = "tex(t)";

if ($str =~ $pattern) {
  print "match\n";
} else {
  print "NO MATCH\n";
}
```

This prints out `NO MATCH`.

The reason for this is the behavior of the `=~` operator.
The thing on the left of that operator is treated as a string, and the thing on the right is treated as a pattern (a regular expression).

Parentheses have special meaning in patterns, but not in strings.

For the specific example above, you could fix it with:

```
my $str = "tex(t)";
my $pattern = "tex\\(t\\)";
```

More generally, if you want to escape "special characters" in `$pattern` (such as `*`, `.`, etc.), you can use the `\Q...\E` syntax others have mentioned.

Does it make sense?

Typically, you do not see a pattern represented as a string (as with `"tex(t)"`).
The more common way to write this would be:

```
if ($str =~ /tex(t)/)
```

Which could be fixed by writing:

```
if ($str =~ /tex\(t\)/)
```

Note that in this case, since you are using a regex object (the `/.../` syntax), you do not need to double-escape the backslashes, as we did for the quoted string.

Comment: Just need some addendum about `quotemeta` and this answer is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the parenthesis:

```
if ( $a =~ /\Q$b/ ) {
    print "matching\n";
}
```

And please, avoid using variable names `$a` and `$b` they are reserved for sorting.
Also, there're no needs to use `printf` here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
my $p = "cat(S1)rat";
my $q = "cat(S1)r";

if ( index( $p, $q ) == -1 ) {
    print "Does not match";
} else {
    print "Match";
}
```